# Store logs in mongo instead of mysql(hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm currently trying to use this plugin : http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging

I would like to store my logs directly in mongoDB. I succeeded to use hibernate and mongo (same time) through a properties like that in my other domains by using  :  static mapWith = "mongo".

Actually my logs is stored in mysql. I like to store this log in mongo.

It is possible to switch the datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the [source code](http://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/blob/master/grails-audit-logging-plugin/AuditLoggingGrailsPlugin.groovy)

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
    application.mainContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { key, datastore ->
        // Don't register the listener if we are disabled
        if (!application.config.auditLog.disabled && !datastore.config.auditLog.disabled) {
```

try adding the following to your DataSource.groovy:

```
 dataSource {
   ...
   auditLog.disabled = true
 }

 mongo {
   ...
   auditLog.disabled = false
 }
```